# Rails App Failing to Save Image Uploads to Amazon S3 Using Paperclip and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, mongoid

I'm trying to store images associated with a `Coupon` object in an Amazon S3 instance. My Rails 3.1 application uses Mongoid for document storage, and I'm not attempting to introduce Paperclip (via mongoid-paperclip) to store images for coupons on Amazon S3.

I've created a permission group on Amazon S3 and added a user; the valid permissions have been added to my application (which I can verify, because if I remove or alter the permissions, I receive an error), but when I attempt to save a file, the file's information is stored in the database, but the file is not uploaded. If I remove mongoid-paperclip from the equation, files are not stored locally either (although I do see that they exist in a temp folder on my local machine and are processed via ImageMagick).

---

### Models

My `Coupon` objects embeds many `Image` objects as such:

```
class Coupon
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # Relationships
  embeds_one :image, as: :imageable

  # Database Schema
  field :name
  field :description
  field :expires, type: Date

  # Validation
  validates :name, :description, :presence => true

end


class Image
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # Relationships
  embedded_in :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_mongoid_attached_file :file,
    :path           => ':id/:style.:extension',
    :storage        => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml'),
    :styles => {
      :original => ['920x920>', :jpg]
    }

end
```

---

I do not see any output from Paperclip in my console or logs and cannot determine how to enable such output. The only information logged in relation to the file being uploaded is as follows, immediately before the page is redirected after successfully updating attributes:

`| Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/ff/vxzlz741287dsr006bv2s59c0000gn/T/stream20111022-80997-o1pqk.png[0]'`

`| Command :: convert '/var/folders/ff/vxzlz741287dsr006bv2s59c0000gn/T/stream20111022-80997-o1pqk.png[0]' -resize "920x920>" '/var/folders/ff/vxzlz741287dsr006bv2s59c0000gn/T/stream20111022-80997-o1pqk20111022-80997-5z9phe.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the identify command provided by your local ImageMagick install. Do you have ImageMagick's libraries installed on your system? I had a similar problem once and it seems that installing ImageMagick from brew fixed it up. FYI: My problem was caused by bad symbolic links, the identify command (and others) simply weren't linked correctly from when I compiled ImageMagick from source.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, This code is not using callbacks.
Paperclip use the callback of after_save to save a image.

```
embeds_one :image, as: :imageable, cascade_callbacks: true
```

You should use cascade callbacks of Mongoid.
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html